# Run multiple Mann Whitney U's using group_by in R

Tags: r, dplyr, pairwise.wilcox.test

I am trying to conduct several Mann Whitney U's which compare the impacts of population on offspring sex ratio skews. I'm using R studio. The dataset looks like:

```
data <- data.frame(
  DamID = 1:50,
  FemaleOffspring = sample(1:10, 50, replace = TRUE),
  MaleOffspring = sample(1:10, 50, replace = TRUE),
  SexRatio = runif(50, min = 0, max = 1),
  BirthPop = sample(c('A', 'B'), 50, replace = TRUE),
  Species = sample(c('R','X', 'Y', 'Z'), 50, replace = TRUE)
)
```

I've written the following line of code

```
library(dplyr)
sumstats <- data %>% 
  group_by(Species, BirthPop) %>%
  summarize(median=median(SexRatio),
            IQR=IQR(SexRatio),
            Min=min(SexRatio),
            Max=max(SexRatio),
            n=n(),
            wilcox_p = wilcox.test(SexRatio ~ factor(BirthPop), data = ., alternative = "two.sided")$p.value
```

Which gives me one p value for the entire dataset when I need a different p value for each species. Not sure what to do about this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code is incomplete, missing at least one close-paren, is that all?

Comment: Use `summarize(data=cur_data())` instead of `summarize(data=.)`. Unfortunately for you, this now fails with `! grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels`, which likely means you have not conditioned your data correctly.

Comment: `cur_data()` is deprecated (or will be soon)

Answer (score 1):

Base R is so much easier here and won't deprecate so soon as `cur_data()`.

```r
wilc_p <- function(X) {
  wilcox.test(SexRatio ~ factor(BirthPop), data = X)$p.value
}

c(by(data, data$Species, FUN = wilc_p))
```

Output:

```
        R         X         Y         Z 
0.5555556 0.5737374 0.9497169 0.6484848
```

Answer (score 1):

I once wrote a function `multiple_tests` as this was a common phenomena on my end. You can find the function on github. Though be cautious of the `multiplicity` effect as the independent testing increases the familywise error-rate

```
remotes::install_github('oonyambu/SLR')
SLR::multiple_tests(SexRatio~BirthPop|Species, data,FUN = wilcox.test)

  Species response grp statistic   p.value null.value alternative                       method
1       R SexRatio A:B        18 0.4908425          0   two.sided Wilcoxon rank sum exact test
2       Z SexRatio A:B        11 0.1806527          0   two.sided Wilcoxon rank sum exact test
3       Y SexRatio A:B        28 0.3154166          0   two.sided Wilcoxon rank sum exact test
4       X SexRatio A:B         6 0.2000000          0   two.sided Wilcoxon rank sum exact test
```

---

data used:

```
set.seed(5)
data <- data.frame(
  DamID = 1:50,
  FemaleOffspring = sample(1:10, 50, replace = TRUE),
  MaleOffspring = sample(1:10, 50, replace = TRUE),
  SexRatio = runif(50, min = 0, max = 1),
  BirthPop = sample(c('A', 'B'), 50, replace = TRUE),
  Species = sample(c('R','X', 'Y', 'Z'), 50, replace = TRUE)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. Use `cur_data()`. When you use `.`, the call to `wilcox.test()` see *all* of the data, and it does not honor the grouping that `group_by` has imposed.
2. When you group by `BirthPop`, then each call to `wilcox.test` gets only `"A"` or only `"B"`, but it needs to see *both* to be able to perform the test.

I suggest do two levels of stats, first on both `Species` and `BirthPop` (to get the majority of your statistics), and then once on just `Species` for your Wilcox tests.

```r
stats1 <- data %>%
  group_by(Species, BirthPop) %>%
  summarize(
    median = median(SexRatio),
    IQR = IQR(SexRatio),
    Min = min(SexRatio),
    Max = max(SexRatio),
    n = n()
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
stats1
# # A tibble: 8 × 7
#   Species BirthPop median   IQR    Min   Max     n
#   <chr>   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1 R       A         0.616 0.562 0.0405 0.710     5
# 2 R       B         0.286 0.357 0.0907 0.740     6
# 3 X       A         0.711 0.713 0.0554 0.966     6
# 4 X       B         0.560 0.204 0.0411 0.980    13
# 5 Y       A         0.471 0.295 0.108  0.815     7
# 6 Y       B         0.425 0.129 0.201  0.686     6
# 7 Z       A         0.365 0.482 0.280  0.910     5
# 8 Z       B         0.452 0.378 0.0737 0.830     2

stats2 <- data %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarize(
    wilcox_p = wilcox.test(SexRatio ~ factor(BirthPop), data = cur_data(), 
                           alternative = "two.sided")$p.value
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
stats2
# # A tibble: 4 × 2
#   Species wilcox_p
#   <chr>      <dbl>
# 1 R          0.931
# 2 X          0.831
# 3 Y          0.534
# 4 Z          0.857
```

We can easily bring these back together with a merge/join operation:

```r
full_join(stats1, stats2, by = "Species")
# # A tibble: 8 × 8
#   Species BirthPop median   IQR    Min   Max     n wilcox_p
#   <chr>   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <int>    <dbl>
# 1 R       A         0.616 0.562 0.0405 0.710     5    0.931
# 2 R       B         0.286 0.357 0.0907 0.740     6    0.931
# 3 X       A         0.711 0.713 0.0554 0.966     6    0.831
# 4 X       B         0.560 0.204 0.0411 0.980    13    0.831
# 5 Y       A         0.471 0.295 0.108  0.815     7    0.534
# 6 Y       B         0.425 0.129 0.201  0.686     6    0.534
# 7 Z       A         0.365 0.482 0.280  0.910     5    0.857
# 8 Z       B         0.452 0.378 0.0737 0.830     2    0.857
```